# CRM Dynamics Contact sub-types

Tags: dynamics-crm

I am very new to Dynamics. I'm trying to figure out if I can use dynamics to create sub-types of the contact entity which have all the common attributes and relationships of the contact entity but each has their own specific attributes as well.

I am thinking about this in an object oriented frame of mind but cannot see how this could be accomplished in Dynamics.

As an example say I was managing schools in a region and I had 3 types of contacts in the system:
School Teachers
School Administrators
School Pupils

All of these would share the attributes from the contact entity but teachers and administrators would have some employee specific attributes and students would have some student specific attributes.

Can someone give me an example of how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set up a picklist on the contact entity with the different "types" on contacts there were. Then attach some javascript to that attribute, so that when it changes, it shows/hides the extra type-specific fields you've defined.

Comment: is that really the only way Microsoft CRM can handle this?

Comment: The way CRM handles activities might be closer to what you're looking for, but there's no way to replicate that functionality in a custom solution.

Is there something about the solution that turns you off?

Answer (score 0):

In SAP there are diffrent Roles for a Business Partner (Contact in your example) maybe its similar in the ms crm, but thats just a clue.